# While loop with a function inside the boolean condition

Tags: php, function, while-loop

I have seen a lot of code online that has a function assigning a value to a variable inside the boolean condition of a while loop:

```
while ($var = testfunction($param1, $param2))
{
  echo "hello world!<br>";
}
```

**QUESTION:**

What is the sequence of events happening inside the boolean condition `($var = testfunction($param1, $param2))`? And what value is being judged by the `while` if it is true or not?

**MY OWN TESTS:**

I have done my own tests. When the function was completely empty, and returned nothing, the code inside the while loop did not execute, however when the function `testfunction()` returned `TRUE`, the code inside the while loop would continue to execute. This leads me to infer that the `while` condition is checking what the resulting value inside `$var` is. So if a boolean is returned into `$var` by the function, then that will be the condition judged by `while`. That also leads me to believe that if `$var` ends up being a number, then anything `==0` will equate to false, and anything `!=0` will equate to true.

These are my deductions, though I have not found any documentation behind them and I could be wrong in my analysis.

Comment: **The meaning of a while statement is simple. It tells PHP to execute the nested statement(s) repeatedly, as long as the while expression evaluates to TRUE**

Comment: I appreciate the well-written question! That said, the easiest explanation is like the documentation (http://php.net/while) says: "It tells PHP to execute the nested statement(s) repeatedly, as long as the while expression evaluates to TRUE."

Comment: @Dagon @JoelHinz When you say expression, what do you refer to exactly? Is the expression literally the variable `$var`? Because if the expression is the statement all together `$var = testfunction(..)` then I would assume it should always evaluate to `TRUE` (which isn't the case with the tests I have executed) because it is always being executed successfully regardless of the returned value.

Comment: No, the `while` loop is evaluating `$var`, whose value is set to the returned value of the function `testfunction(...)`. So as long as the function returns true, or anything truthy (like a number, a string, an array, an object), the while loop continues to run. In other words, `while` loop performs a boolean check on the `$var`: and to see what is evaluated as true/false in boolean mode, [refer to the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: To expand on @Terry - basically it says run the loop until something in $param1 or $param2 change to make the function return false instead of true.

Comment: TRUE is rather broad in php, FALSE, is a little more absolute

Comment: You will get all falsy values at [http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

Comment: Questions about programming basics are OT, how is this not closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole expression is being executed, and its value converted to a [boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

```
($var = testfunction($param1, $param2))
```

First off, `testfunction(...)` will be called, and afterwards the assignment will take place. According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php):

> The value of an assignment expression is the value assigned.

so whatever has been returned and assigned to `$var` will be  converted to a boolean and evaluated by the `WHILE` loop. If if the value assigned is null, [], 0, etc, code block from the while loop will not be executed. Otherwise it will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the `while` is based on the condition that `$var` exist/got a value "truthly".

You would have written that :

```
$var = testfunction($param1, $param2);
while ($var){
 echo "whateveryouwant";
 $var = testfunction($param1, $param2);
}
```

It would have been the exact same behavior at the execution, and it makes it clearer for you as in the first place the `while ($var = testfunction($param1, $param2))` condition is based on the value of `$var = testfunction($param1, $param2)` which is the value of `$var` which is equal to `testfunction($param1, $param2)`.

You could also have written `while (testfunction($param1, $param2))` the behavior would have been the same and cleaner if you don't use the returned value elsewhere than in this condition.

Comment: A short script to demonstrate what this answer explains: `$foo = array(3,2,1,0,1,2,3); $i = 0; while($bar = $foo[$i]) {echo $bar."\n";$i++;}`. Run it and it should become obvious how the expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

The while condition performs a type coercion to a boolean value on the value of `$var`, after the called function has run and its return value was assigned to `$var`. So, if the function returns a value that evaluates to FALSE, the while loop exists, otherwise it will run its code block for this iteration.

the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) shows exactly what values evaluate to false, see the following list:

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> the boolean FALSE itself
>
> the integer 0 (zero)
>
> the float 0.0 (zero)
>
> the empty string, and the string "0"
>
> an array with zero elements
>
> an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
>
> the special type NULL (including unset variables)
>
> SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
>
> Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).